# Does instantiating a class redefine the class including all of its methods?

Tags: python, class

I'm making a program that will go through at least 1,016,064 gear permutations on Diablo 3. I've been experimenting with different theoretical implementations and I decided that I wanted to use classes to represent each permutation rather than having to deal with massive and convoluted dictionaries. With this method I can store an instance and then replace it when a new permutation is superior to the former.

In any case it takes my computer (i7-3632QM) about 40 seconds go through all of the permutations just doing about 30 flops per permutation, and I cant even imagine how long it'll take if it has to define all 50 methods each time a class is instantiated. Anyway, this is what I think it'll look like:

```
class perm:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.x = 10
    self.y = 5
    self.z = 100

    for item in args:
      if hasattr(self, item): 
        getattr(self, item)()

    self.val_1 = self.x * 2
    self.val_2 = self.y * 5
    self.val_3 = self.z/(self.z+300)

  def head_1(self):
    self.x += 5
    self.z + 200

  def head_2(self):
    self.x += 10
    self.y += 10

  def feet_1(self):
    self.y += 5
    self.z += 250        

  def feet_2(self):
    self.x += 10
    self.z += 500

current_best = perm('head_1','feet_2')
```

Comment: How are you using this class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you plan to do with this class, but this is almost certainly not the best way.

Comment: `I decided that I wanted to use classes to represent each permutation` I don't think that means what you think it means. But yeah your code makes very little sense.

Comment: FYI, `getattr` allows a default argument that's returned if `not hasattr(obj, attr)`. You could give it a NOP function: `for item in args: getattr(self, item, lambda: None)()`

Comment: Though of course that all makes no sense, since it's being passed arguments in the constructor that are supposed to refer to some unknown methods in the class body of a non-inheriting object. *argh*!

Comment: I think it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Note also that I'm *assuming* he thinks that `self.val_N` will update their values as his methods change `self.x`, `self.y`, and `self.z`

Comment: @Adam Smith I think I was pretty clear what I want to do with this. Also I don't know what your correction has to do with the question, I'm not trying to optimize an example, I just want to know if classes are like functions in that calling a function spends time defining functions inside the function each time it is called (I think that's correct).

Comment: @user4131185 since literally every person who's commented has either said "This doesn't make sense," asked for more information, or straight up told you that you're asking the wrong question: I'd say it's ***definitely not clear what you're trying to do.*** My point with `getattr` was completely tangential

Comment: @Falmarri maybe not, maybe so; you don't understand what I'm asking and I only know what I've learned writing scripts using help docs. I have zero computer science education or any for that matter. But further explanation: in my example, there are 4 possible versions of the perm class: perm('head_1','feet_1), perm('head_1', 'feet_2'), perm('head_2','feet_1'), perm('head_2','feet_2'). In actuality like I said there are over a million different combinations, and I would like to see which 'perm' has the best attributes.

Comment: @user4131185 how do you know which one is best?

Comment: @AdamSmith Ok while I still don't think my question was ambiguous I probably should have left out the actual example and what it was for and just stuck with the title question.  Since I din't think this was a difficult question,  maybe someone would chime in with a more efficient method in case that this method wouldn't be viable in practice. I can deal with it taking an hour to go through all of the combinations but I can imagine at least 200 more operations per permutation more than my preliminary testing plus function definitions (and more)... too much. I wish googled told me my title q

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the *correct* way to do this is to make objects for each of the gear options you have, then a *function* that calculates them all.

```
import itertools


class Gear(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # I have no idea what Gear should do...

class Headpiece(Gear):
    ...

class Legs(Gear):
    ...

# etc


def calculate_perm(gear_tuple):
    result = do_some_calculation_over(gear_tuple)
    return result

best = max(itertools.permutations(all_your_gear), key=calculate_perm)
```

You could even create one class that's analogous to your `perm`, though I'd give it a more descriptive name:

```
class EquipmentSet(object):

    slots = ['head', 'legs', ... ]

    def __init__(self, head=None, legs=None, ...)
        self.head = head
        self.legs = legs
        ...
        self.equipment = [getattr(self, item) for item in self.slots]

    @property
    def x(self)
        return sum(item.x for item in self.equipment)

    # similar for y and z

    @property
    def val_1(self):
        return self.x * 2

    # similar for val_2, val_3

    # implement dunder rich comparison methods?


result = max(EquipmentSet(*gearset) for \
             gearset in itertools.permutations(all_your_gear))
```

Comment: Yep, that's a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are just as a example. These lists should contain `Gear` class, which instances knows what type of 'bonuses' gear gives.

```
import itertools
headpieces = ['headpiece1', 'headpiece2', 'headpiece3']
armors = ['armor1', 'armor2']
weapons = ['weapon1', 'weapon2']

print list(itertools.product(headpieces, armors, weapons))
# result: 
[('headpiece1', 'armor1', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece1', 'armor1', 'weapon2'),
 ('headpiece1', 'armor2', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece1', 'armor2', 'weapon2'),
 ('headpiece2', 'armor1', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece2', 'armor1', 'weapon2'),
 ('headpiece2', 'armor2', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece2', 'armor2', 'weapon2'),
 ('headpiece3', 'armor1', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece3', 'armor1', 'weapon2'),
 ('headpiece3', 'armor2', 'weapon1'),
 ('headpiece3', 'armor2', 'weapon2')]
```

This code gives you all possible gears in **lazy** way (without passing it to `list()` it returns generator), is optimized (`itertools` are implemented in C) as is elegant. Note that in each element there is only one headpiece / weapon / armor. May be generalized to additional piece of gears.

After that you'll just have to write some kind of aggregator which takes input gear and returns 'score'.

Comment: Ah yes, `itertools.product` I'm sure will give him a better result than my `itertools.permutations`, but it's impossible to know for sure since we don't know what his objects look like

Answer (score 0):

Well I decided to use itertools, a module I have no experience with (but that will change after this!), and I've already half made the script making a test. It works so I might as well finish it even if it isn't the most efficient way, although I'm open to suggestions...

```
import time, itertools

class Barb:
  def __init__(_, args):
    _.elements = ['arcane','cold','fire','lightning','poison','physical']

    _.strength         = 5460 # max ancient str
    _.vitality         = 140    
    _.armor            = 10188
    _.all_res          = 250
    _.resistances = {element:7.7 for element in _.elements}
    _.dodge = 0

    _.armor_bonus_percent = .25
    _.all_res_bonus_percent = 0
    _.life_bonus_percent = .25
    _.elemental_damage_reduction = 1

    _.regen = 10730
    _.life_on_hit = 8035
    _.life_per_fury_spent = 0
    _.life_percent_per_second_regen = 0

    _.damage_mod = 1
    _.cc = .05
    _.cd = 2.8
    _.ias = .25
    _.attacks_per_second = 1.69
    _.ww_damage_percent = 0
    _.dibs = 0
    _.cdr = 1
    _.elemental_damage_bonus = .2
    _.bastions = False
    # apply gear bonuses
    for arg in args:
      getattr(_, arg)()

  def helm_1(_):
    _.cc += .06
    _.ww_damage_percent += .15
    _.life_bonus_percent += .23
    _.resistances['arcane'] += 210

  def helm_2(_):
    _.cc += .06
    _.vitality += 1000
    _.life_bonus_percent += .23
    _.resistances['arcane'] += 210

  def torso_1(_):
    _.vitality += 650
    _.life_bonus_percent += .15
    _.resistances['fire'] += 210

  def torso_2(_):
    _.all_res += 120
    _.vitality += 650

  def pants_1(_):
    _.vitality += 650
    _.armor += 700
    _.resistances['physical'] += 210

  def pants_2(_):
    _.vitality += 650
    _.all_res += 120

  def bastions_1(_):#ring set
    _.strength += 1000
    _.cc += .12
    _.cd += 1
    _.resistances['physical'] += 210
    _.resistances['poison'] += 210
    _.bastions = True

  def bastions_2(_):
    _.strength += 500
    _.cc += .12
    _.cd += 1
    _.cdr *= .92
    _.resistances['physical'] += 210
    _.resistances['poison'] += 210
    _.bastions = True

  def bk_1(_): # (str, dmg, cdr) + (str, cdr, vit)
    _.strength += 2000
    _.damage_mod *= 1.05
    _.cdr *= .9 * .9
    _.vitality += 1000

  def bk_2(_): # (str, dmg, cdr) + (str, dmg, loh)
    _.strength += 2000
    _.damage_mod *= 1.1
    _.cdr *= .9
    _.life_on_hit += 18000

def best_score():
  def available_items(prefix):
    #automagically check barb for possible item variants of the item slot 'prefix'
    # so more can be added at a later time
    r = []
    i = 1
    while True:
      name = '%s_%s'%(prefix, i)
      if hasattr(Barb, name):
        r.append(name)
      else: return r
      i += 1

  gear_slots = [
    'helm','torso','pants','bastions','bk']

  helms, torso, pants, bastions, bk = [available_items(i) for i in gear_slots]

  gears = itertools.product(helms, torso, pants, bastions, bk)
  bestOffense = {'gear':[],
                 'health':0,
                 'mitigation':0,
                 'damage':0}
  elapsed = time.time()
  while True:
    try:
      args = next(gears)
      barb = Barb(args)

      armor = barb.armor * (1 + barb.armor_bonus_percent)
      damage_reduction = armor / (armor + 3500)
      resistances = {res:(barb.resistances[res] + barb.all_res) \
                     * (1 + barb.all_res_bonus_percent) for \
                     res in barb.resistances}
      elemental_dr = {res:resistances[res]/(resistances[res] + 350) \
                      for res in resistances}

      health = barb.vitality * 100 * (1 + barb.life_bonus_percent)

      aps = barb.attacks_per_second * (1 + barb.ias)
      damage_mod = barb.damage_mod * (1 + (barb.strength / 100))
      damage_mod *= (1 - barb.cc) + (barb.cc * barb.cd)
      damage_mod *= 2.25 if barb.bastions else 1
      damage_mod *= 1 + barb.elemental_damage_bonus

      dust_devils = 25 * damage_mod * (1 + barb.dibs + barb.ww_damage_percent)
      min_elemental_dr = elemental_dr[min(elemental_dr)]
      mitigation = 1 - ((1-damage_reduction) * (1-min_elemental_dr))

      if dust_devils > bestOffense['damage']:
        bestOffense = {'gear':args,
                       'health':health,
                       'mitigation':mitigation,
                       'damage':dust_devils}
    except: return bestOffense, time.time() - elapsed
```

Answer (score -2):

Python [static methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) will stop the interpreter making a new function in memory for every instance of a class. You can only use it for functions that don't need an instance to operate on though, i.e. functions that don't use `self`.